# Photoshop: how to create a semi-transparent gradient stroke?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cs6, gradient

Is there any way to create a gradient that fades from one colour out to transparent as I cant find any tutorials or work out how to do so, I'm trying to use this for a stroke gradient but it wont give me any option to lower the transparency.

Comment: There're transparent gradients already in the default gradients

Answer (score 2):

The stops at the top of the gradient in the gradient editor control opacity...

[image: Photoshop gradient editor]

It's all explained here:

- [**Use gradients in Photoshop - Adobe Support**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/gradients.html#gradient_editor_overview)